# $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)} f(x,y)$: find another path with a different limit, yet the limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

[Question 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtY3B.jpg) *(text reproduced below)*

> The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by
>   $$
> f(x,y) = \frac{(x-1)(y+1)^3}{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^6}
> $$
>   a. Approach the point $(1,-1)$ by straight lines and calculate the limit of $f(x,y)$ along those straight-line paths. (*Hint:* $\lim_{u\to0} f(1+u, -1+ku)$ for $\in\mathbb{R}$.)
>
> b. Show that there is another path along which $f(x,y)$ limit as calculated in part (a), as $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,-1)$. Does the function $f$ have a limit as $(x,y)$ tends to $(1,-1)$?

Question B asks to show another path with a different limit for $f(x,y)$. Yet the limit exist what other path can approach the function without contradicting with the existence of the limit.

Comment: If you are asked to find two paths yielding different limits, why would you think the function has a limit overall?

Comment: Because the limit does exist http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x,y)-%3E(1,-1)+((x-1)(y%2B1)%5E3)%2F((x-1)%5E2%2B(y%2B1)%5E6). But it looks the question is contradicting itself or I missing something huge.

Comment: You may be missing something in that you have an utter faith in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Just as a fun fact: as right now wolframalpha also shows that the limit does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit does *not* exist, even if you seem to think so based on Wolfram Alpha.

*First advice:* in these situations, do **not** take Wolfram Alpha's result as the word of the law.

Now, try the parameterization $(x,y)=(1+u^3,-1+u)$, when $u\to 0$. Spoiler below: place your mouse on it to reveal the text.

> $$f(x,y) = \frac{(x-1)(y+1)^3}{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^6}= \frac{u^3\cdot u^3}{u^6+u^6} = \frac{1}{2}\xrightarrow[u\to0]{} \frac{1}{2}.$$

The idea? We want to chose $a,b>0$ such that $x=1+u^a$, $y=-1+u^b$ lead to nice simplifications in $f(x,y)$, with a limit that is not $0$. The exponents above do that.

Comment: Thank you for you explaination, I will no longer blindly rely on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: In my experience (limited, I have to say), Mathematica/Wolfram is good for univariate limits, but has to be taken with a grain of salt (or, rather, give results hard to interpret) in multivariate or more complicated scenarii.